# Solutions of a exponential diophantine equation involving the $\sigma$ function

Tags: nt.number-theory

As usual $\sigma_k(n)$ denotes the sum of the $k$-th powers of the positive divisors of an integer $n.$
Note that $k$ is also an integer so that it may be negative.

There are no odd perfect numbers known but there are many numbers $N$ such that
$$
\sigma(N) \equiv 2 \pmod{4}
$$
i.e.; many numbers
of the form:

$$
N = p^{4k+1}m^2
$$
with $\gcd(p,m)=1$ and $p$ a prime number with $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}.$

Since
$$
2\sqrt{2}
$$
equals the minimum of the $2z+1/z$ when $0 < z \leq 1,$
attained for
$$
z=z_0 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
$$

by putting

$$
z =\frac{p^{4k+1}}{\sigma(p^{4k+1})}
$$

It may have some interest the

Question:  For which  numbers $k$ and prime numbers $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$
the $z$ above is `close` to $z_0$, say  appears as a convergent in the continued fraction of $z_0.$

question inspired  by some MO posts of Arnie Dris:

a) In his notation I am asking here when the sum below is `minimal`

$$
I(p^{4k+1}) + I(m^2) = \sigma_{-1} (p^{4k+1}) + \sigma_{-1}(m^2)
$$

b) Arnie wanted $2N=\sigma(N)$ so that in his case

$$
I(p^{4k+1}) = 1/z
$$

and

$$
I(m^2)= 2z
$$

so that

$$
I(p^{4k+1})+I(m^2)=2z+1/z
$$

Comment: I'm confused. First, $\sigma_k()$ is defined but never used. Second, where $2z + 1/z$ comes from?

Comment: Notation
`$\sigma_k$` is used in line 4, with $k=1$, in line $13$  with $k=1,$ and  twice
in line $-1$ with $k=-1.$

Arnie wanted $2N=\sigma(N)$ so that in his case

$$
I(p^{4k+1}) = 1/z
$$

and

$$
I(m^2)= 2z
$$

so that

$$
I(p^{4k+1})+I(m^2)=2z+1/z
$$




Comment: For clarity comment above is incorporated to question.


Comment: @Luis, I just happened to look at this one again today, and I think you should have $I(p^{4k+1}) = 2z$ and $I(m^2) = 1/z$ owing to parity constraints.

Comment: $\sigma(p^{4k+1})$ is even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$z = \frac{p^{4k+1}}{\sigma(p^{4k+1})} = \frac{1-p^{-1}}{1-p^{-(4k+2)}} > 1-p^{-1}.$$
Clearly, for a fixed p, the larger is $k$ the closer is $z$ to this lower bound.

Since the lower bound is greater than $z_0$ (for any prime $p\geq 5$) and grows with $p$, it is beneficial to take $p$ as small as possible. The smallest such prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is $p=5$.

Therefore, for any prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $k\geq 0$, we have
$$z - z_0 = \frac{p^{4k+1}}{\sigma(p^{4k+1})} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} > \frac{4}{5} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} > 0.09$$
where
$$\frac{4}{5} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{5^{4k+1}}{\sigma(5^{4k+1})}.$$